# Pick a zip file from SD card using intent

Tags: java, android, file, android-intent, zip

want to get all .zip files from an SD card using intent in my android app for unzipping one of them(by selecting and getting it onActivityResult).

**here is my code.**

```
private void openZip(int reqCode) {
        Intent intent = (new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT));
        intent.setType("file/zip");
        startActivityForResult(intent, reqCode);
    }
```

The above code is not working.

Comment: `file/zip` is not a valid MIME type. Try `application/zip`.

Answer (score 0):

### What is wrong ?

---

You are providing it with `file/zip` which is **not a valid format**.

### What to use?

---

You need to use `application/zip`.